# Efficiently packing rectangles on a strip of paper

Tags: code-challenge

### Algorithm for nesting submited jobs to reduce paper roll usage.

Working with a 36" large format printer, with paper roll as source (150feet=45meters).

With a delay loop on print server queue: waiting 30 seconds before printing in case another job are comming too.

At begining of (perl) print script, it do a list of paper sizes as an output from `gs -sDEVICE=bbox`, with all pages of all jobs in last 30 seconds and return only one indexed list of page sizes, like:

#### Input sample

```
 0:807.4780x562.6371
 1:562.6370x807.4780
 2:1700.0000x4251.0000
 3:550.6150x786.1020
 4:594.0000x840.9060
 5:504.7200x761.0000
 6:368.3280x761.0000
 7:1193.0000x1685.0000
```

All values are in 1/72 inches (postscript dot).

The roll is `36 x 72 = 2592` dot with but have 15dot margin.

The orientation of roll is: `Y=<width; max 2562 dots>` and `X=<length: max not specified but ~127Kdots>`. So when start printing, the top-left corner is one right side of printer and sheet is going out from the *top of postscript page*.

[image: nesting plot on roll paper]

The goal of the challenge is to build the quicker algorithm to choose **the smallest** paper length to cut out from the roll and the way of nesting all pages on this paper sheet (adding a little fixed space between plots for cutter)... and having smallest number of cut (see drawing: *reducing cut*).

#### Fixed Variables

```
ROLL WIDTH        = 36 x 72
PRINTER MARGIN    = 15 x 2
PLOT SEPARATION   = 15
```

**Important:** The pages may have to be re-ordered and rotated in order to find the best arrangment.

Desired output: First paper length alone on first line, than all page, one by line, in format: `<Index>:<X offset>x<Y offset><Rotation flag (R)`

#### Output sample

```
4281
0:1715x0
1:1715x577R
2:0x0
3:1715x1400R
...
```

Note: This sample may be wrong: I'm not sure now if `R` are rightly placed or have to be inversed. That's doesn't matter in that:

- `R` stand for rotation and is a flag. But his meaning stay free it could be used to say *to rotate* or *to not rotate* (the rotation angle could be `90°` or `270°`, as you prefer;-).

#### Number of cuts

This have to be calculated only for **separating** plots, not do finalize margins. This mean: *One separation = one cut, not two*. But the rush have to be dropped!

In others word: border added could be *separator/2* to *plotter margin*.

A cut have to be **straight** and **end to end** on a dimension of a sheet or already cutted sheet.

## Goal:

**The winner** will be the first to offer a full useable implementation of its algorithm able to process upto 20 rectangles in less than 30 seconds. (With shebang or command line sample). Any language commonly used in production is acceptable.  (meaning: no brainf@#k, but lisp could be accepted.)

**Bonus** if in case of one fixed size of paper length due to one big plot, all other jobs are placed in the meaning of **reducing** number of paper **cut**.

Comment: Is there a scoring system/is the winning answer determined by popularity?

Comment: The title might read more clearly as: "Efficiently packing rectangles on a strip of paper".  "Nesting rectangles" suggests placing rectangles within rectangles that are within rectangles that are within….

Comment: Could you please clarify the scoring? Is the goal just to output "a" paperlength and some arrangement? Or the "best" arrangement? In what sense? And could you explain how the number of paper cuts is calculated (maybe using your example)?

Comment: Rectangle bin packing is not for the faint of heart.  See http://clb.demon.fi/files/RectangleBinPack.pdf

Comment: I thought I could find beefy people, on *Programming Puzzles & Code Golf* ;-)

Comment: Isn't this one of the millennial prize problems? The unsolvable math problems, like the pattern of primes. Rectangle packaging is a crazy hard problem because the answer is never intuitive, the example you show isn't even the most efficient way to pack. :o

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw I think no: It's solvable be successive tries, (also a little expensive). And you're right: *it's never intuitive* and yes, I think my example is not perfect.